# Выделение цветом (не)правильных ответов в тесте

Tags: jquery

Мне нужно сделать простенький тест, чтобы пользователь выбирал ответы из всех вопросов, а потом нажимал кнопку отправить, и в каждом вопросе выделялись зелёным верные, а красным неверные варианты.

Я сделал пока так, но не работает: когда выделяю несколько ответов и нажимаю кнопку отправить, то ничего не происходит, а хотелось бы, чтобы после того как нажал на отправить, чекбоксы, которые я выбрал, подстветились красным, если это не правильный ответ, или зелёным, если правильный.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".questionsubmit").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var answer;
        $('.question').each(function() {
answer = $(this).find('input').attr('checked', true);
if(answer.hasClass('correct')) {
answer.addClass('checked-right');
}
else {
answer.addClass('checked-wrong');
$(this).find('correct').addClass('checked-right');
}
 });
    });
});
</script>
```

```css
.checked-wrong {
  background-color: #E12F52;
}
.checked-right {
  background-color: #4CE12F;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
<div class="question">
   <p>первый вопрос</p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" class="correct" value="1417"> 1417</p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" class="wrong" value="1680"> 1680</p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" class="wrong" value="1883"> 1883</p>
</div>
<div class="question">
   <p>второй вопрос</p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" class="correct" value="1417"> 1417</p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" class="wrong" value="1680"> 1680</p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" class="wrong" value="1883"> 1883</p>
</div>
   <p><input type="submit" class="questionsubmit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: добавьте описание: что именно не работает, что хотелось бы исправить, какое ожидаемое поведение

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы создавать новый вопрос, отредактируйте лучше стары

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, не не, это я попросил вынести в отдельный, там совсем другой в итоге

Comment: @Grundy поправил описание, я просто не могу понять из за чего ничего не происходит, видимо там в цикле что то не так

Comment: @Grundy, визуально - один-в-один. Вы бы хоть как-то локализовали проблему, раз ТС не в состоянии этого сделать. А то работа за автора и все такое...

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, тут просто разметка поменялась, и само ожидаемое поведение

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, Вы всем `checkbox` устанавливаете атрибут `checked` в `true`. Во-вторых, класс следует присваивать родительскому элементу. А ещё можно упростить весь код.

Вот рабочий код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".questionsubmit").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.question input:checked').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('correct')) {
          $(this).parent('p').addClass('checked-right');
        }else{
          $(this).parent('p').addClass('checked-wrong');
        }
      });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k9o3p42a/

Comment: а как сделать, что бы если пользователь выбрал не правильный вариант, то он подсветился красным, а правильный, который нужно было выбрать, зелёным?

Comment: просто мне нужно, что бы если я ответил неправильно на первый вопрос, то он не только подсветился красным, но и правильный ответ, который я не выбрал, подсветился зелёным, что бы пользователь знал, какой ответ всё таки правильный, что бы ему не пришлось щёлкать по всем вариантам, что бы узнать правильный ответ

Comment: @Alex, а я думал с подсветкой разобрались в прошлом вопросе :-)

Comment: @Alex, просто добавьте код `$('.correct').parent('p').addClass('checked-right');`, который выделит все верные ответы.

Comment: @Alex, а вообще весь код можно сильно упростить, избавившись от циклов и условий:
`$(".questionsubmit").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.correct').parent('p').addClass('checked-right');
  $('.wrong:checked').parent('p').addClass('checked-wrong');
});`

Comment: @Grundy да, извините, разобрались, просто нападают на меня со всех сторон :)

Comment: @СебастьянПерейро спасибо большое, Вы очень помогли